# SharePoint frontend connectivity issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, 2019, server-farm, front-end

I have 2 frontend servers in my SharePoint 2019 farm and one of them hosted our custom API but if restart or shutdown one of them, all SharePoint will be down.

The 2 frontend servers have same services running. Any idea where can I find the problem?